# R markdown df_print options

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have a R markdown document in RStudio, where a data.table is printed.  I want to set the data frame print options to control printed number of rows and columns, as described [here](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/html_document_format.html#data_frame_printing).

Here is a minimal example .Rmd file:

````
---
output: 
  html_document: 
    fig_height: 8
    fig_width: 10
    df_print: paged
---

```{r}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
cars
```
````

**Where/how do I set the `rows.print` option?**

I've tried this:

```
---
output: 
  html_document: 
    fig_height: 8
    fig_width: 10
    df_print: paged
    rows.print: 25
---
```

which doesn't work (still at default 10 rows), and this:

````
```{r}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, rows.print=25)
cars
```
````

which also doesn't work.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The `knitr::opts_chunk$set(rows.print=25)` option setting applies only to subsequent chunks, hence in the minimal example it doesn't change the setting.

The option can be set in the chunk as shown in `chunk1` or globally in `opts_chunk` for subsequent chunks.

````
```{r chunk1, rows.print=15}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, rows.print=25)
cars #15 rows printed
```

```{r chunk2}
cars #25 rows printed
```
````

Comment: I wasn't able to get this to work, my rows still show up as 10 (the default). Am I missing something?

Comment: @nachocab Did you set `df_print: paged` in the header under HTML output?