# displaying all the rows and columns of tibble in R-markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I'm working on an R markdown file. The results of analysis are shown in the form of `tibble` but in order to see all the columns and rows, I need to click to expand. However, since I'm going to knit the file into html, I need to display all the columns and rows in the R markdown file. I did a search and came up with the following codes:

```
options(tibble.width = Inf) # displays all columns.
options(tibble.print_max = Inf) # to show all the rows.
```

However, I don't know where to put them. I placed them before and after my code, but it didn't work. MY codes are:

1. `head(df)`
2. `summarise(mean_cov= ..., median_cov=...., sd_cov=...., ...)`

Thanks.

Comment: Is widening also possible for only a single column? I'm fine with some columns being collapsed, but a specific one contains an identifier which needs to be fully available for copy-pasting in the .md output.

Comment: I think the answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40893742/r-markdown-df-print-options) is relevant. Essentially set `{r rows.print = n}` in your code chunk header.

Answer (score 12):

a `tibble` is a specific type of data.frame (try `class(df)`), and it has its own method to print, which is frustrating when you want the full thing.

As it's still a data.frame though you can use the method for `data.frames` and it will print everything, try:

```
print.data.frame(df)
```

or

```
print.data.frame(head(df))
```

or

```
print.data.frame(summarize...)
```

Note that `as.data.frame` will have the same output

Comment: But the problem is that I want to see all the columns but only first few rows when using the head() function, and I want to see all the columns and rows when using the summarise() function.

Comment: just wrap them into a `print.data.frame` statement, see updated answer

Comment: if still not clear please update your post with a reproducible example (input and expected output), this always makes things much easier

Comment: When I wrap it, I get the following error:

Error: This function should not be called directly

Comment: This is why we need the reproducible examples ;)

Comment: Yeah, but you don't have access to the data. Right?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: This doesn't work.  The problem he's experiencing isn't caused by tibble, its caused by rmarkdown deciding to show only the first x rows.

Comment: This is why we need reproducible examples

Answer (score 9):

```
print(your_tbl, n = 1e3)
```

or

```
your_tbl %>% print(n = 1e3)
```

Replace `n` with a number larger than the max number of rows you'll encounter. (And hopefully 1e3 = 1000 will do, since a table with even 100 rows is pretty hard to understand by eye.)

Comment: Same problem as the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can also use `View(df)` to see the data in spreadsheet format.

Answer (score -1):

try `head(data.frame(df))`, `head(data.frame(df), 40)`,  `head(data.frame(df), 40)` etc