# Print more columns before break in r markdown html

Tags: r, dataframe, r-markdown

Whenever I print a dataframe in r markdown and knit it into html, the html always displays only 5 columns, before breaking, and printing the next 5 columns. Is there a way to set it to print more columns before breaking?

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40893742/r-markdown-df-print-options) here shows how to it for rows but not for columns. I tried doing:

````
```{r chunk1, columns.print=7}

```
````

but it does not work and I can't seem to find any questions asked about this on stackoverflow. The reason for doing is that if I have a dataframe with for example 17 rows, it will print the dataframe in 4 breaks/paragraphs, which makes the html output very long and messy.

Comment: I guess it depends on the spacing the column name or the value in the column takes.  If I try this with `mtcars` it prints all the 11 columns in the single row without any breaking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were so close, you need `cols.print` NOT `columns.print` and we need an extra YAML argument to allow for paging, to allow the user to see more of the data columns, if they want. I used 3 columns in my example to easily see the results.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Daniel"
date: "6/17/2021"
output: 
  html_document:
    df_print: paged
---

```{r, cols.print=3}
mtcars
```
````

[image]

I would suggest using `df_print: paged` as it allows for more dynamic tables for your document.